# CICD for ADF: how to restrict access to the adf_publish branch without breaking the CICD process?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-data-factory

as part of our project we are linking an azure datafactory instance to azure git using the steps documented by microsoft. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control) We are hoping to restrict access as much possible to avoid user error. In keeping with that goal we are trying to determine if there is a way to configure the branch policies in azure git so that only the adf instance can update the adf_publish branch after a successful publish. **No User** should be able to update the adf_publish branch from the repo itself. In the past we configured the branch policy to disable any pushes to the adf_publish branch. However also this prevented the adf instance from pushing its changes. So we trying to determine if there is a possible solution to for this goal.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is more about branch security rather than Azure Data Factory itself.
If you want to control or limit control for users - simply select a particular branch (in this case it's **adf_publish**) in Azure DevOps and go to **Branch security**:

[image]

Then you can set up required permissions per group or per user, like *Contribute* or *Force Push*:
[image]

Comment: We already looked into branch security and disabled user access. However this also prevented the adf from pushing to the branch as well. The adf seems to use user credentials to author pushes to the adf_publish branch. So disabling user access also blocks the adf. But we don't want individual users to be able to commit to the adf_publish branch without publishing from the adf first. So we are wondering if there is a solution to give access only to the adf itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is the option to put the ADF in Git has the option to disable "Disable publish (from ADF Studio)", this option does not generate changes in the adf_publish, only in the ADF.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).